# Windows Server 2016 - How to install Lotus/IBM/HCL Notes 11

Tags: windows-server-2016, lotus-notes

We need to install the Notes client (version 9, 10, or 11) on a Server 2016. This is a clean install of the client. No previous versions were ever installed on this box. The server is also not running any other Domino software at this time.

Installation attempts however fail and roll back. The System event log shows three similar entries at the time of installation. Which pertain to Multi-user Cleanup Service, HCL Notes Smart Upgrade Service and HCL Auto Update Service. The complaint coming from the OS is that each of these is " marked as an interactive service. However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services. This service may not function properly."

The relating registry setting to allow interactive services on Windows is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows -> NoInteractiveServices. We set this to 0. However, this did not help. Also, research shows that this setting is no longer respected and that interactive services are no longer allowed on Windows server 2016 and up.

We do not require any update services to be running, I am not sure about the Multi-user Cleanup service though.

Any ideas how to install the Notes 11 on Windows 2016 would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!